# How to Unit Test WPF + TPL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unit-testing, task-parallel-library

I'm running a simple WPF application which uses a Event-Based/TPL approach to process data.
Three classes are used in this Example(View, Presenter, Model)

```
Snip of Presenter:

internal void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<Person>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetPerson(id)).ContinueWith(UpdateTest, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

public Person GetPerson(int id)
{
    Person p = Model.GetPerson(id);
    return p;
}

private void UpdateTest(Task<Person> task)
{
    Person p = task.Result;
    window.tb_test.Text = p.ID + " " + p.Name; // PROBLEM HERE
}
```

So, I'm getting an event from the View, start a new Task to get Data from my DB or Service and  update the UI afterwards. Work perfectly fine.

Now I want to create a Unit test for this scenario. Is the displayed value correct?

```
[TestMethod]

SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

WPF.MainWindowView mwv = new MainWindowView();
mwv.btn_test.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
mwv.tb_test.TextChanged += (s, e) => waitHandle.Set();

waitHandle.WaitOne();

Assert.AreEqual("43 displayvalue", mwv.tb_test.Text);
```

WPF Application works fine, but there's an InvalidoperationException at tests. I tried using a Dispatcher for updating UI components by calling

```
window.tb_test.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate {window.tb_test.Text = t.ID + " " + t.Name});
```

in UpdateTest, but the "tb_test.textChanged" event doesn't get called at my testing module altough the app itself works perfectly fine.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Where is textChanged comes from? I cannot see it has been used in your SUT(System Under Test). What 'specific' scenario you want to test, your test method name is missing as well. In your SUT, you have private void UpdateTest(Task<Person> task), where this one get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `window` is a WPF `Window` and `tb_test` is a WPF `TextBlock`.

First, let me preface all of this by saying that the WPF threading model makes it a bit of a chore to run unit tests against live WPF objects.  Personally, I find the benefits of these kinds of coded tests to be minimal, compared to the hassle of dealing with all of this, especially when following the MVVM design pattern.  Moving the important logic into more test-friendly locations (read: data binding and commands that manipulate view model objects) would make these tests seem a lot more redundant.

If you can restructure your design so that you can get all the "important" logic in a more testable location, then that's what I would recommend trying.  I don't know what the history of this code base is, so I don't really want to leave it at that.  If you can't, and/or if you are just curious, then let's go down the rabbit hole...

When you set the current `SynchronizationContext` in the test, you're using a plain `SynchronizationContext`, whose `Post` is implemented using the `ThreadPool` (i.e., the callback could be executed on any thread).  So when the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` goes to schedule the task continuation, it has the "update the `TextBlock`'s `Text`" code run on what might be a different thread, breaking WPF's "must be executed on the `Dispatcher` thread" rule.

Your suggested fix to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` would probably solve your immediate problem if the `Dispatcher` were running.  I don't see `Dispatcher.Run` or `Dispacher.PushFrame` anywhere in the posted test code, so I think that effectively turns anything that would be executed on that `Dispatcher` into a no-op (goes into a queue that never gets read from).  When the application is running normally, the code that Visual Studio auto-generates for you calls `Application.Run` at the end of the executable's entry point, which (eventually) gets around to calling `Dispatcher.Run` for you so it can start processing messages like "display the main window" and such.

You'll probably notice that after calling `Dispatcher.Run`, it blocks the dispatcher on whatever thread you're calling it on until you tell it to shut down from another thread.  After telling it to shut down, there's no way to start up another `Dispatcher` on that thread... so in essence, either each test needs to spin up and spin down its own separate thread (annoyingly slow if you want to write more than a handful of these kinds of tests, at least for me), or you're maybe going to benefit from using the fancy `[AssemblyInitialize]` / `[AssemblyCleanup]` methods for MSTest so you can manage just a single `Dispatcher` pump for all tests in that project (which is what we've done).

Once you get past these, you'll probably also find out that fetching `mwv.tb_test.Text` in the test needs to happen on the `Dispatcher` thread as well.

You're also risking a race condition, since the event raised by `RaiseEvent` **could** (depending on how you approach the threading concerns) terminate before the `TextChanged` handler gets wired up in your test, meaning that the `ManualResetEvent` might sometimes block forever even after everything else.

Comment: "I find the benefits of these kinds of coded tests to be minimal, compared to the hassle of dealing with all of this, especially when following the MVVM design pattern."

Comment: At the first moment, I though it would be a good idea to test against a "real" WPF window, instead of only the logical parts of the code. I'm going to reconsider the structure + refactoring bad parts.

I appreciate your patience to answer my sort of "newbish" and maybe not clear question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Joe's answer, you need a dispatcher running on a thread for this to work.

See this answer for code in a unit test that should work: [Task.ContinueWith and DispatcherSynchronizationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412851/task-continuewith-and-dispatchersynchronizationcontext/20414367#20414367)